# R legend: placement and sizing of symbols and labels for barplots in base graphics

Tags: r, layout, plot, legend

I am using `layout` to create 15 panels: the first 3 panels being titles followed by 12 barplots using base R. I want to include a legend for multiple plots along with the title in the 3rd panel.

There are 3 legend items in a horizontal legend. I'm struggling to resize and position these elements to that they fit neatly and legibly under the title.

The default patch size is too large but I can find no way to independently resize the patch symbol and the text (`pt.cex` does not work, because I am not using a point symbol). Using `cex = 0.5` to resize the legend gives me the patch size I want but the text is far too small (I want text cex = 1).

Is there a way to resize the symbols in `legend` independently of the labels?

```
# layout graphs in a grid of 3 cols by 5 rows
final <- layout(matrix(c(1:15), 5, 3, byrow = TRUE))

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "Direction of wind gusts", cex = 1.5) # cex rescales text
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "Direction of extreme wind gusts", cex = 1.5)
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "Direction of plants", cex = 1.5)
# add legend below third title text
legtext <- c("Shrub","Graminoid","Cushion")
legend("bottom", legend=legtext,
       fill=gray(c(0.6, 0.3, 0.9)), horiz = TRUE, x.intersp = 0.3,
       bty="n", cex = 0.5, inset = c(0,-0.3))
```

Following this code are my 12 barplots in the remainder of the grid.

I have also tried a workaround which solves the sizing problem but seems to make the spacing impossible. The workaround is to plot the patches and the text separately on top of each other. I can then tweak the vertical offset to position the legend items.

However I cannot work out how to control the horizontal spacing of the legend elements so that all 3 legend items fit in the space. Most of the legend is truncated and not visible and the patches and text do not align properly horizontally (big gaps between them).

```
# workaround is to plot a legend with just symbols (no labels) scaled 0.5
legend("bottom", legend= "",
       fill=gray(c(0.6, 0.3, 0.9)), horiz = TRUE, x.intersp = 0.1, 
       bty="n", cex = 0.5, inset = c(0,-0.3))
# then a legend with only labels, scaled to 1
legend("bottom", legend = legtext,
       horiz = TRUE, x.intersp = 0.02, bty="n", cex = 1, inset = c(0,-0.7))
```

I realise that exporting or zooming the plot layout can display things differently than the screen layout/resolution in R Studio, but still cannot adjust the legend symbols and text so that they fit neatly on one line.

Comment: One option is to use `pch=22, pt.cex=0.5, pt.bg=gray(c(0.6, 0.3, 0.9))`.

Comment: It is thinking outside the box to use a point symbol for a boxplot legend, but it works! With a bit of tweaking of `text.width` and `cex` values I have got the result I wanted. Thanks.